# DefaultMembershipProvider => Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider

I'm running into issues when I try to instantiate a new DefaultMembershipProvider (system.web.providers).

```
DefaultMembershipProvider _provider = new DefaultMembershipProvider();
```

After this I would assume settings are loaded from the web.config but this is not the case. For example *minRequiredPasswordLength* remains 0.

Here's my membership settings:

```
<membership>
    <providers>
        <add applicationName="/"
             connectionStringName="MyDB"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
             enablePasswordReset="true"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
             minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
             passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
             requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
             name="DefaultMembershipProvider"
             type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </providers>
</membership>
```

I can create new users via the asp.net configuration tool without problem so my database connection seems ok.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why u are instantiating DefaultMembershipProvider yourself? any reason?

Comment: I must admit I'm quite new to it. I just don't see any other way to get to the methods it provides...

Comment: Should I just be using the system.web.security.Membership class then?

Comment: You don't need to instantiate the class yourself. Unless you are trying to do something special all you have to do is configure the things in web.config and the framework will take care of instantiating that class with populating the values from web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to instantiate it yourself.  You should just be able to access the static properties and methods of the [`Membership` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.aspx) directly (you'll notice that most of them are static).

For instance, this would give you the minimum required password length that you have configured:

```
int minPassLength = System.Web.Security.Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength;
```

You can do a number of other convenient things with the static methods, like getting all your users (with the [`GetAllUsers` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8swhya.aspx)) or updating specific user information (with the [`UpdateUser` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.updateuser.aspx)).

Also, I believe you should have the `type` in your membership settings set to

```
type="System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider"
```